# why map() function always returns something even if condition statement does not match?_ java script

Tags: javascript

take a look at this example:

```js
let my_array = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8]



test = my_array.map(element=>{
    if(element!==1){
        return element
    }
})


console.log(test)
```

why map() function always return something if the statement does not match?

I know map function iterate over the indexes of array. but why returns null? we said return only if the statement is true.

how we can avoid null in return of map()?

update: I needed combination of map() and filter():

```
let my_array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
test = my_array
  .filter(element => element !== 1)
  .map(element => element * 2);

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.map` will always create an array with the same number of items as in the original array. That's how it works. If you don't want to produce an array with the same number of elements, use `.filter` instead:

```js
let my_array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
test = my_array.filter(element => element !== 1);

console.log(test)
```

`.map` is only suited for transforming *every element* of an array into another value, eg:

```js
let my_array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
test = my_array.map(element => element * 2);

console.log(test)
```

If you need to both remove values *and* transform an element, then you can use both `.filter` and `.map`:

```js
let my_array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
test = my_array
  .filter(element => element !== 1)
  .map(element => element * 2);

console.log(test)
```